# cv::KeyPointsFilter::retainBest isn't working as intended

Tags: c++, opencv

[cv::KeyPointsFilter::retainBest](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/de/db2/classcv_1_1KeyPointsFilter.html#adeb110acade85bf7a110968c6d856a1c)

Doesn't seem to be behaving as I would have thought, I am interested in getting a fixed number of points on varying sizes of images (for classification), I am using OpenCV 2.4.10.

Executing the following code on a couple of images I got: 110 and 122 for the keypoints.size()

edit: more info the actual output:

```
# keypoints: 478
new # keypoints: 122
filter not working properly?
```

and

```
# keypoints: 4575
new # keypoints: 110
filter not working properly?
```

As always, thanks in advance.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>

#define MAX_KEYPOINTS 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    //cv::initModule_nonfree();
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1]);

    if (!image.empty())
    {
        cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("FAST");

        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
        detector->detect(image, keypoints);

        std::cout << "# keypoints: " << keypoints.size() << std::endl;

        cv::KeyPointsFilter::retainBest(keypoints, MAX_KEYPOINTS);

        std::cout << "new # keypoints: " << keypoints.size() << std::endl;

        if (keypoints.size() != MAX_KEYPOINTS)
        {
            std::cerr << "filter not working properly?" << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "failed to load image " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No I didn't, considered submitting a bug to OpenCV what version are you using? Since posting I have updated to 3.0.0 but I haven't tried the code yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a bug. Retain best will give you the best nth element in an array. So you must have at least n elements. But it also looks for the elements that are bigger than a certain threshold since Fast may give ambiguous results. As a result you can end up with more than n keypoints. This is the OpenCV code:

```
struct KeypointResponseGreaterThanThreshold {
    KeypointResponseGreaterThanThreshold(float _value) : value(_value) { }
    inline bool operator()(const KeyPoint& kpt) const {
        return kpt.response >= value;
    }
    float value;
};

void retainBest(std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints, int n) {
   std::nth_element(keypoints.begin(), keypoints.begin() + n, keypoints.end(),
            [](cv::KeyPoint& a, cv::KeyPoint& b) { return a.response > b.response; });
   float ambiguous_response = keypoints[n- 1].response;
   std::vector<KeyPoint>::const_iterator new_end =
   std::partition(keypoints.begin() + n, keypoints.end(),
            KeypointResponseGreaterThanThreshold(ambiguous_response));
   keypoints.resize(new_end - keypoints.begin());
}
```

But if you want exactly n keypoints, just do it your self, it's easier and faster. Of course you need at least n keypoints :)

```
void retainBest(std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>& keypoints, int n) {
    if (keypoints.size() > n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            keypoints.clear();
            return;
        }
        std::nth_element(keypoints.begin(), keypoints.begin() + n, keypoints.end(),
            [](cv::KeyPoint& a, cv::KeyPoint& b) { return a.response > b.response; });
        keypoints.resize(n);
    }
}
```